# Converse of positive definite over $\mathbb{Z}$ characterization

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I had a number theory class where Binary Quadratic Forms of the form $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ was introduced. Let $d=b^2-4ac$ be the discriminant of $f$.

> Definition: $f(x,y)$ is positive definite if $f(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Note that my lecturer defines positive definite over $\mathbb{Z}$, and not the usual $\mathbb{R}$. Now we can show by completing the square, $f(x,y)=a(x+\frac{b}{2a}y)^2+(c-\frac{b^2}{4a})y^2$

> Theorem: If $a>0$ and $d<0$ then $f$ is positive definite

where $c-\frac{b^2}{4a}=\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}=-\frac{d}{a}$

Now my question is whether the converse of this statement is true

> Converse Statement: If $f$ is positive definite (over $\mathbb{Z}$) then $a>0$ and $d<0$

The emphasis (over $\mathbb{Z}$) here is important, since if we were to try to prove it over $\mathbb{R}$, the proof might not work.

Proof of converse over $\mathbb{R}$:

Part 1. Set $y=0$, then $f(x,0)=ax^2$. Therefore $a > 0$

Part 2. Set $x = -\frac{b}{2a}y$, then $f(-\frac{b}{2a}y, y)= (c+\frac{b^2}{4a})y^2$. As we have $a>0$, therefore $d < 0$.

Now the problem with this “proof” carried over to $\mathbb{Z}$ is Part 2, where $\frac{b}{2a}y$ may not be in $\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore I could not show that $d<0$.

I think this converse result still holds, but we were not able to produce a proof. My classmate proposed a proof which does not work, which motivates me to ask here. Here’s the proof that does not work:

Proof: Set $y=1$. Therefore $g(x) = f(x, 1) =ax^2 + bx + c$ is now a quadratic equation. As we have $a>0$, we conclude that $d<0$.

The problem with this “Proof” is that the quadratic equation $g(x)$ runs over $\mathbb{Z}$, and not $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, it may still be possible that $d>0$ but $g(x)$ is positive definite. This is the case when say, $h(x)=x^2-0.8x+0.1$ takes negative values only on an interval $(0.15, 0.65)$ between $0$ and $1$. Therefore this $h(x)$ is still positive definite over $\mathbb{Z}$, despite having some negative values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now we could not use this counter example $h(x)$ because it uses non-integer coefficients, while the Binary Quadratic Form is defined with Integer coefficients.

So I was not able to prove or disprove this converse statement. To provide a disproof, we just need some integer coefficients $a,b,c$ where $d>0$ but $f(x,y)>0$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. To provide a proof, we may need to show the following

> Possible Proof(?): Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that if $d>0$ and $f(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f$ does not have integer coefficients.

If my “Possible Proof” is true, then we have shown the contrapositive of the converse statement, basically showing that the counter-example scenario could not happen, but I am not sure if this statement is true.

Thanks for reading my long post. It would be great if you could provide a proof or disproof to my converse statement.

Comment: if an irrational number $t$ causes $a t^2 + bt + c < 0,$  then taking a rational $x/y$ sufficiently close to $t$ causes $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 < 0$

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for the comment. I accept this as a Proof. Basically I've been looking at the question from the wrong perspective. We can show using real analysis techniques that $d<0 \implies \exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}: f(x,y)<0$